# Best way to post user input with React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I know that any request, and every asyncronous block of code, must be written inside the .useEffect() method (in case of functional components).
UseEffect should run my code when the components mount, then what's the best way to make a post request which post data given from a user?
Thanks a priori.

Comment: How is a user submitting the data inputs? Do you expect a user to click a button, press the enter key, etc?

Comment: Hey, that's not need to make async requests inside a `useEffect` hook. Probably if you want to fetch something `onMount`, you will need to call that fetch inside or outside there (calling a function from `useEffect`). For making a POST it's actually the same, it depends. If you want to make your call after some state update, add to the dependency array that state and make the request, or, attaching a function to an event from a click i.e.

Comment: Please share some code snippet.

Comment: @Hyetigran yes by clicking a button or with the enter key

Answer (score 1):

**Not every** asynchronous code must go into the useEffect hook block. The useEffect hook is in many cases used to perform side effects(like making a request) when a functional component has just mounted or it's updated. Please refer to [React Docs - useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to understand better.

One way to go about making a post request with data received from a user is:

- Save the data received from the user in a piece of state
- Attach a function that posts the request to a submit button
- Get the piece of data from the state and use it to make the post request

The useEffect hook is not in any way involved in this case

Comment: Thanks you blow my doubt away! :)